# magnetic field in simple train

Tags: magnetic-fields

I would like someone to check this image 
waynesthisandthat.com/images/HT%20994.
jpg and be extremely kind and explain how to figure out which end of battery becomes north and south in simple electric train and do we have any electric field as well or not??
http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/How%20To%20Build%20The%20Simplest%20Electric%20Train.html